# PregMach with php GET method =

Tags: php

I have a page test.php in which I have a list of names:

> name1=992345&name2=332345&name3=558645&name4=434544

In another page test1.php?id=name2 and the result should be:

```
33234
```

I've tried this PHP code:

```
<?php 
$Text=file_get_contents("test.php");
if(isset($_GET["id"])){
   $id = $_GET["id"];
   $regex = "/".$id."=\'([^\']+)\'/";
   preg_match_all($regex,$Text,$Match); 
   $fid=$Match[1][0]; 
   echo $fid; 
} else {
   echo "";
}

 ?>
```

But it dosn't work.

if the list is with `''`

> name1='992345'&name2='332345'&name3='558645'&name4='434544'

it works. how to change to work?

Comment: You've got `'` quotes in your regex, so why are you surprised they're required to be present in the text you're matching? "Here you go, one red couch, as ordered". "But it's red! I didn't want red!"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php 
  $Text=file_get_contents("test.php");
  if(isset($_GET["id"])){
     $id = $_GET["id"];
     parse_str($Text,$data);
     echo $data[$id];
  } else {
     echo "";
  }

?>
```

This code should work.

Answer (score 2):

```
parse_str($Text,$data);
echo $data[$_GET["id"]];
```

[parse_str](http://php.net/parse_str)

Comment: I think you should pass `$Text` instead of `$id`. +1 anyway.